# Couldn't connect to Larvel homestead database with MYSQL workbench

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, database, php7

I am unable to connect to laravel homestead via mysql workbench

here is how i connected

[Homestead Connection http://simple.harry.zone/linux/homestead_connect.png](http://simple.harry.zone/linux/homestead_connect.png)

but i am facing the below issue

[Homestead Issue http://simple.harry.zone/linux/homestead_issue.png](http://simple.harry.zone/linux/homestead_issue.png)

**Edit:**

Here are the details as requested by Gerath in the comments below

1 : The server is running in localhost, 127.0.0.1 only

2.) The homestead server is using 33060 port virtually ( 3306 as guest, and 33060 as host )

3.) I am not sure

4.) he username and password for databases is homestead / secret which is default in laravel homestead .

Here is the details for pt 1 and 2

[Homestead Port http://simple.harry.zone/linux/homestead_port.png](http://simple.harry.zone/linux/homestead_port.png)

Comment: Have you tried the 4 points in the popup window?  What was the outcome? You don't have a specific question here (they end in question marks - ?) Also _Plz Plz help me !!!_ doesn't help :-)

Comment: Hey @garethTheRed, i have edited the details , plz see

Answer (score 1):

I Solved the problem myself , the mistake was that i was not running it as adminstrator

```
sudo mysql-workbench
```

worked perfectly for me !

Comment: You may find that you can connect as a normal user if you follow this answer: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/3496. I haven't got mysql-workbench on my laptop, so I can't check for you.